# Page navigation broken in IE11

Tags: html, internet-explorer, anchor

I have a page with 4 links and two of them don't work in IE. They're fine in Chrome & FF.

I've read that IE requires some text in the anchor tags, but I tried that and there's no difference.

This is my html:

```
<section id='link1' class='menuBox'>
  <a href='link1'>
    <h1>Link 1</h1>
  </a>
</section>

<section id='link2' class='menuBox'>
  <a href='link2'>
    <h1>Link 2</h1>
  </a>
</section>

<section id='link3' class='menuBox'>
  <a href='link3'>
    <h1>Link 3</h1>
  </a>
</section>

<section id='link4' class='menuBox'>
  <a href='link4'>
    <h1>Link 4</h1>
  </a>
</section>
```

The funny thing about this is that I have links 1 & 2 set as large boxes on a first row and links 3 & 4 are boxes that look very similar to the other two but are on another row.

I also have another page in my app with the same layout and I have the same problem on that page as well.

Can't figure out what's causing this. The two elements are completely dead. The hovers don't work, the links don't work, they're just sitting there with no actions happening at all.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to close `<a>`

Replace `<a href='link1'` for `<a href='link1'>` (do the same on following anchors)

Comment: Thanks, but that was just a typo. I'm converting from Jade and just forgot those. Will edit the question now.

Comment: If you disable CSS do they work? Wondering if there's any rule affecting them. Doesn't seem like a IE11 issue since the first two are working (although I can't test that on my end)

Comment: They DO work when css is disabled. Will search for the culprit now.

Comment: Found the culprit `z-index` Not sure why that breaks the linking, but there you go. Thanks @rafg

Comment: Cool! Glad you found it!